# Utilizing bitwise & to detect a number as a power of 2 in Java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-and

While working on a problem on Hackerank I saw this code in the code that was given to us:
`(num&num-1)==0` and my question is why does this tell me whether or not the variable `num` is a power of 2?

I noticed the code works perfectly.  What I believe is happening is the bitwise & operator is used to convert the variable `num` to binary and then 1 is subtracted from it and I also believe the 1 is being converted to binary?  I am not quite sure exactly what is happening but with numbers like `8` the result is always equal to 0 and with numbers like 9 it isn't.  Can someone explain what is happening under the hood that makes this code work?

Comment: In any number, if the last bit is true the number is odd (because that is the one bit, 2 to the 0th power is one).

Comment: How does that help with the number 10 which is an even number. 10 clearly isn't a power of 2.

Comment: Look at the bit pattern of `Integer.toBinaryString(10)` and `Integer.toBinaryString(9)`; digital computers are **really** simple (there are only two states per bit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a power of two is translated into binary representation, it contains exactly one 1 and 0s on the remaining position, e.g. (in 8-bit representation):

> 2^4 = 0001 0000

Subtracting one from such a number sets the 1-bit to zero, and all bits behind it to one:

> 2^4 - 1 = 0000 1111

That means, for powers of two, that there is no bit set in both cases, and `x & (x - 1)` is zero.

If a number other than a power of two is translated into binary representation, it contains at least two 1s, e.g. (in 8-bit representation):

> 12 = 0000 1100

Subtracting one from this number sets the least significant 1 to 0, and all 0s behind it to 1s:

> 12 - 1 = 0000 1011

But since this number contains at least two bits, there is still at least one bit that hasn't been modified. So, in `x & (x - 1)`, at least one bit is set, and the number is not equal to zero.

This doesn't work in one case, though, as it will detect 0 as a power of two (since `0 & -1 == 0` is true).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize it was doing 8 & 7 and assumed it was doing 8&8 - 1 which was simply 1000 & 1000 = 1000 then 1000 - 0001 which  0111 i.e. 7 and that is why I couldn't figure out what was going on.

Comment: Agreed. Looking at the bit patterns makes it clear.

Answer (score 2):

> the bitwise & operator is used to convert the variable num to binary and then 1 is subtracted from it and I also believe the 1 is being converted to binary?

No. There is no conversion to binary happening. Numbers **are** binary. That's all computers can use: binary numbers.

In binary, 8 is `1000`. If you subtract 1 to it, you get 7: `0111`. So, when you use a bitwise and on these two numbers, you get

```
  1000
& 0111
------
= 0000
```

For non-powers of two, you'll always have more than one 1 in the number, and subtracting 1 to it will leave the leftmost 1 as is. For example, with 9, you would have

```
  1001
& 1000
------
= 1000
```

Comment: Ah OK, so the num - 1 is executing before num&num. I believe that's what threw me off. Therefore I get num & (num - 1).  Is this correct?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize it was doing 8 & 7 and assumed it was doing 8&8 - 1 which was simply 1000 & 1000 = 1000 then 1000 - 0001 which  0111 i.e. 7 and that is why I couldn't figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

`9` is represented as `1001`

`8` is represented as `1000`

Now `9&8` will be

`1001` & `1000` which is `1000`

Let's try this with `8`

`8` is represented as `1000`

`7` is represented as `0111`

Now `8&7` will be

`1000` & `0111` which is `0000`

For `odd` numbers, there will be at least `one bit` that does not cancel out. Whereas for `even` numbers, they cancel out.

To understand the `logical AND (&)`, check this out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction_(AND)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I didn't realize it was doing 8 & 7 and assumed it was doing 8&8 - 1 which was simply 1000 & 1000 = 1000 then 1000 - 0001 which  0111 i.e. 7 and that is why I couldn't figure out what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the binary representation. A number that is a power of 2 is a 1 followed by a series of 0s (e.g., 2 is 10 in binary, 4 is 100, 8 is 1000, etc). If you subtract 1 from it, you'll get a series of 1 matching the 0s from the original number. If you then & between them, every 1 will be matched with a 0, and the result would be 0. For any number that isn't a power of 2, you'll get at least one digit of 1 in matching places between `num` and `num-1`, and thus get a non-zero result when you & them.